# What is the easiest way to encrypt websockets messages using stomp and spring boot?

Tags: javascript, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I would like to prevent users from viewing the plaintext of messages sent via web sockets (using browser dev tools, for example). I am using Spring Boot on the server-side, and the following javascript in the AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.socket = new SockJS('/stomp');
$scope.stompClient = Stomp.over($scope.socket);

$scope.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    $scope.stompClient.subscribe("/topic/message", function (data) {
    ...
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way for this masking to be implemented?

Comment: simple: send `Blob()`s. ex: `socket.send(new Blob(["Hello World"]));` use `FileReader()` on the other end to unpack.

Comment: @Quentin: WSS/TLS doesn't affect the devtools viewing of data at all. if using gzip, then even wireshark captures on "plain ws" are not easily human-readable. on that note, non-hacker-blocking can be had by `atob(btoa("Hello World"))` to stop casual reading. (un-nest)

Comment: You're giving the *source code* to the browser, you can't hide the messages from the user.